# To write summation of numbers with a for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, numbers, sum

Basically I'm writing a method where I want to find the summation of whole numbers with a for loop.

The output should be something like this:

```
Enter value of number 1: 23
Enter value of number 2: 23
Enter value of number 3: 23

The sum is: 69
```

The user will be able choose of many numbers to be added.

My code currently looks like this:

```
private void ReadInput()
{
    Console.Write("Number of values to sum?");
    numOfInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();

}    

private void ReadInput()
    {
        Console.Write("Number of values to sum?");
        numOfInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private void SumNumbers()
    {
        int index;
        int num = 0;
        for (index = 0; index < numOfInput; index++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please give the value of no " + index);
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

how should I fix it

```
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int index;
    int num = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < numOfInput; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please give the value of no  <whole numbers>  " + index);
        num += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        num = sum;


}
}
private void ShowResults()
{
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------\n");
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is \t{0}", sum);
```

Seems to be the solution + the classes above it are still used but yes.

Thank y'all very much

Comment: Do you always want three inputs or continue input until user hits <enter>

Comment: The user will be able to enter how many numbers they may enter, I added this method to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 private static void SumNumbers()
        {
            int numOfInput = 3;
            int index;
            int num = 0;
            for (index = 1; index <= numOfInput; index++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please give the value of no " + index);
                num += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

            }
            Console.WriteLine("The sum is:" + num.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine(); // to keep console alive 
        }
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
private void SumNumbers()
{
    int index;
    int num = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < numOfInput; index++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please give the value of no " + index);
        num += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The sum so far is : "+num.ToString("N0")+". Enter another number to continue summation.");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Maximum input received. Total is: "+num.ToString("N0")+".");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as per your need:

```
int index;
int num = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Number of values to sum: ");
int numOfInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (index = 1; index <= numOfInput; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please give the value of no " + index);
    num += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + num);
```

The following output will be generated:

> Number of values to sum: 3
>
> Please give the value of no 1
>   23
>   Please give the value of no 2
>   23
>   Please give the value of no 3
>   23
>   The sum is: 69